# How to not shuffle array after submitting or refreshing page in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, refresh

I have an array like this:

```
$aTotalQuestions = range(1, 10);
shuffle($aTotalQuestions);
```

This is what I am doing with my array:

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($aTotalQuestions as $total) {
    echo "<tr><td>$total</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

output for example:

```
4
5
8
6
1
2
10
9
3
7
```

Every time when I press a submit button or refresh my page, it is shuffling my array again.
I don't want to shuffle my array after another page refresh, but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: save it in session and check if session is set then do nothing else shuffle.

Comment: Make sure the state is persisted. For example in a session, database, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save shuffle array, eg. in session.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['shuffled'])) {
    $_SESSION['shuffled'] = range(1, 10);
    shuffle($_SESSION['shuffled']);
}

echo "<table>";
foreach($_SESSION['shuffled'] as $total) {
    echo "<tr><td>$total</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: `shuffle` returns boolean, not the new array. It must be called before assigning it to the session variable

Comment: @MateiMihai: Sure, I've updated (many thoughts, hands faster than brain) :-)